# Angular NgRx Effect concatMap multiple HTTP requests based on condition

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an action which is mapped to HTTP request via `concatMap` method because I need those HTTP requests to be sequenced. I'd like to improve this behavior by sequencing only HTTP requests with same object ID that's sent in the action.

This is the code I have that's working, but making all the requests sequentials. I am using it for inline editing of records and I want to make it that if user changes `value1` for record with ID:1 and then changes `value2` for ID:1 these calls will be sequential, but if he changes `value1` for record with ID:2 in the meantime then it would do the save request for record with ID:2 in parallel with those save requests for record with ID:1. Is this possible with some map method?

```
@Effect()
saveEffect = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType(saveAction),
  concatMap(action => this.service.save(action.oID, action.saveData)
    .pipe(
      map(...),
      catchError(...)
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` to group your actions by id. This operator will emit every incoming action on an Observable for its specific group.

```ts
saveEffect = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType(saveAction),
  groupBy(action => action.oID),
  mergeMap(group$ => group$.pipe(
    concatMap(action => this.saveAction(action))
  ))
);

saveAction(action): Observable<any> {
  return this.service.save(action.oID, action.saveData).pipe(
    map(...),
    catchError(...)
  )
}
```

Comment: Simple and easy solve by using this snippet, thank you very much